One and only one vs One in crow's foot notation
Am I using one and only one correctly? I have read so many articles online on differences between one and only one vs one and I'm still confused.

I.e.

a customer can exist with zero, 1 or many (multiple) orders but an order can
only be associated to one customer (the same customer with the same id, hence one and
only one)
a dish can be cooked by multiple chefs, but different chefs will cook the same one and only dish (e.g. dish_id 1 = carbonara, where chef 1 cook dish_id 1 and chef 2 cook also dish_id 1)

Or does this make more sense below, since a customer (although the same customer with same id) can appear more than once in orders) and in orders table it does not restrict to the same customer only so a single dash makes more sense? Same for dishes, although referring to the same dish with same dish_id, orderitems and chefdishes does not restrict to only one single dish, i.e. they can have dish_id1, dish_d2, etc.?
thank you in advance - your help is much appreciated.


It is unclear to me whether you're asking what the relationship should be, or how to correctly represent a given relationship in a diagram.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Just to help you along in fixing this question, your question is currently assuming that internet strangers are able to naturally infer exactly how your database should be modeled, as if there's only one way to model a relationship between these named entities. This is not the case, and I suspect that your lack of investigation on the finer requirements are also the root cause of your confusion. Revisit what your goals are, attempt to apply them with the knowledge you have, and come back with a concrete question that explain (a) your expectation (b) your attempt and (c) the specific problem.

The correct notation for your modelling intent in Crow's foot notation is the second diagram:  the double bar says "one and only one".
The simple bar in the first diagram is not wrong but ambiguous.  It just says "one", without specifying if it's always one or if it can be zero.
If you want to specify unambiguous "zero or one",  you'd need to use a circle and a bar (same notation logic that for zero, one or many).
In case of doubt,  keep in mind that the "one and only one" is to be read in relation with the opposite side:

"each order has one and only one customer", whereas "each customer can have zero, one or more orders".  Orders with no customer would not make sense since you wouldn't know where to send the order nor who would have to pay.
"each dish/chief combination is about one and only one dish".  Indeed, without such a dish the dish/chief would not really be a combination.

By the way, the dish/chief table is an association table that seems to have as sole purpose to implement a "many to many" relationship (alternatively, you could chose not to show this table and instead show a direct many to many relationship between chief and dish).
